# How can I delete a specific image on tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to make a game that hides the area behind it until you click on a specific area, but I can't figure out how to delete a specific image on the canvas because I used a loop to create the images and can't set a specific tag to it. PS I didn't put the full code in this code won't work if you run it I just need to know what to put in the tags section.

```
`from tkinter import *

def cover():
    b = 0
    c = 0
    for i in range(0,y):
        for j in range(0,x):
            s.create_image(b,c, anchor=NW, image=coverimg, tags="I don't know what to put in here")
            b += 33
        b = 0
        c += 33
        
def reveal(event):
    for i in range(0,y):
        for j in range(0,x):
            s.delete("I don't know what to put in here")
    
s.bind("<Button-1>", reveal)`
```

Comment: you could store the images somewhere first (in an array) and then access them from the array

Comment: Save the images in a list or dictionary.

Comment: Whether or not you use tags to identify the images, you will still have to use a list or a dictionary, as the two previous comments suggested. It is best simply to use the images' IDs, instead of tags, to identify them.

Comment: For your case, you can use something like `f"img_{y}_{x}"` as the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from tkinter import *
imgtags=[]
def cover():
    b = 0
    c = 0
    for i in range(0,y):
        for j in range(0,x):
            s.create_image(b,c, anchor=NW, image=coverimg, tags=f"img{x}_{y}")
            imgtags.append(f"img{x}_{y}")
            b += 33
        b = 0
        c += 33
        
def reveal(event):
    for tag in imgtags:
            s.delete(tag)
    
s.bind("<Button-1>", reveal)
```

Here, We are creating an `f-string` to the name the tags. Then, We are adding the tag that we had created into the `imgtags` list. So, now this list will contain all the tags that we need.
Now, when you want to do the reveal,we use a `for` loop to access each and every tag and then pass it to the `s.delete` so that the images get deleted.
I hope that it clarifies your doubt.

If you want to know more about `f-strings`,see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/).

Comment: `for tag in tags` should be `for tag in imgtags`.

Comment: @acw1668,Thanks for pointing out the typo, I have edited it now